# Calculating the delta between multiple variables grouped by user ids

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

How might I calculate the delta between multiple variables grouped by user ids in a "long" data frame?

Data format:

```
d1 <- data.frame(
    id = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 2),
    purchased = c(rep(c(T, F), 3), F, T, T, F), 
    product = rep(c("A", "B"), 5), 
    grade = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 5, 1, 2),
    rate = c(10, 12, 10, 12, 12, 14, 22, 18, 10, 12),
    fee = rep(c(1, 2), 5))
```

This is my roundabout solution:

```
dA <- d1 %>%
    filter(product == "A")

dB <- d1 %>%
    filter(product == "B")

d2 <- inner_join(dA, dB, by = "id", suffix = c(".A", ".B"))

d3 <- d2 %>% 
    mutate(
        purchased = if_else(purchased.A == T, "A", "B"),
        dGrade = grade.B - grade.A, 
        dRate = rate.B - rate.A, 
        dFee = fee.B - fee.A) %>%
    select(id, purchased:dFee)
```

All of this just seems terribly inefficient and complex. Is `tidyr::spread` or another dplyr/tidyr function appropriate here? (I couldn't get anything else to work)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `gather/spread`.  Reshape the data from 'wide' to 'long' using `gather`, grouped by 'id', 'Var', we get the 'product' based on the logical column 'purchased', get the difference of 'Val' for 'product' that are 'B' and 'A', and `spread` it from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(d1, Var, Val, grade:fee) %>% 
           group_by(id, Var) %>% 
           summarise(purchased = product[purchased], 
                     Val = Val[product == 'B'] - Val[product == 'A'])%>% 
           spread(Var, Val)
#     id purchased   fee grade  rate
#   <dbl>    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1         A     1     1     2
#2     2         A     1     1     2
#3     3         A     1     1     2
#4     4         B     1    -2    -4
#5     5         A     1     1     2
```

The OP's output ('d3') is

```
d3
#  id purchased dGrade dRate dFee
#1  1         A      1     2    1
#2  2         A      1     2    1
#3  3         A      1     2    1
#4  4         B     -2    -4    1
#5  5         A      1     2    1
```